# cannot import com.avaje.ebean.Model for Playframework

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I worked before with Playframework 2.1.2. Now I tried to work with the latest version. I tried to import the `play.db.ebean.Model` like in 2.1.2 but it didn't work. Then I found that this was replaced by `com.avaje.ebean.Model`. But in the jdk 1.8.0_45 there is no package `com.avaje...`

I believe that I have made an absolute stupid mistake but I can't see it... How do I set up Play to work with Ebean?

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes the IDE is the reason: something goes wrong in that huge "black box". So, if the configuration is valid for sure, try to restart the IDE. The miracle can happen.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you are using Play 2.4.6. Did you read the [JavaEbean documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean)? The docs are pretty clear in my opinion.

Steps:

To enable it, add the Play Ebean plugin to your SBT plugins in `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

And then modify your `build.sbt` to enable the Play Ebean plugin:

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

Specify where your models live in the `application.conf`:

```
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

After this run a `./activator clean run`. This will update and download all needed dependencies including Ebean dependencies!

After that create your model like:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;
import play.data.format.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

@Entity
public class Task extends Model {

    @Id
    @Constraints.Min(10)
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    public boolean done;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date dueDate = new Date();

    public static Finder<Long, Task> find = new Finder<Long,Task>(Task.class);

}
```

Comment: Yes. I read the documentation... Everything done... Again... But there is still no com.avaje Package...

Comment: If you say that you have followed the steps from the docs and still is not working, the only way I can help is if you create a sample repository on github that I can check out. Otherwise it will be guessing what is wrong, while on my project the steps above were sufficient to make it work.

Comment: Your answer saved my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was absolutely racking my brain for hours! I followed the documentation carefully and then tried a bunch of different combinations that didn't work. Anyway...

If you're using Eclipse (I'm just assuming), try running `activator eclipse` on the command line. It will add the play-ebean.jar to .classpath so Eclipse knows where it is. Then, make sure you refresh the project in Eclipse. play-ebean.jar should appear under Referenced Libraries and you'll be able to import `com.avaje.ebean.*` into your model classes.

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest release (see the documentation:  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaEbean#using-model-superclass)

You will need to import 'io.ebean.Model' instead of 'com.avaje.ebean.Model'